# How to Show Persian DateTime in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, gregorian-calendar, persian-calendar

I am Windows Forms desktop application in C#.net. I saved `DateTime` in Gregorian calendar in SQL Server database. Now I want to display `DateTime` in Shamsi (Jalali/Peersian) calendar format in `DataGridView` column.

How can I show Persian `DateTime` in `DataGridView` while the data in data base is Gregorian `DateTime`?

Answer (score 2):

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
  // Sets the CurrentCulture property to U.S. English.
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
  // Displays dt, formatted using the ShortDatePattern
  // and the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.
  Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d"));

  // Creates a CultureInfo for German in Germany.
  CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
  // Displays dt, formatted using the ShortDatePattern
  // and the CultureInfo.
  Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d", ci));
```

you could pass in you own culture i am not sure what you cultures code is

Comment: your solution does not work in win 7!!!!

Comment: @user6641321 What do you mean with that?

Comment: I mean that I have a datetime field in the database so When I show data of table in datagridview this field is gregorian but I want to show persian date.

Answer (score 1):

You change the default format of your column to the custom format.

Example if your column the 3rd column:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

You change the format whatever you want.